# Why won't my ~/.Xmodmap file load on login?

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I created the following `~/.Xmodmap` file as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/185345/why-wont-my-xmodmap-command-run-on-startup-login/185374#185374).

```
keysym Delete = Menu
keysym Menu = Delete

clear Lock
keycode 0x42 = Escape
```

In other words, swap `Delete` and `Menu`, and make `Caps Lock` an additional `Escape`.

The next time I logged in, Ubuntu asked me if I wanted to load `~/.Xmodmap` as expected. I loaded it, but nothing happened (either then or on subsequent logins). If I manually run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`, it works as expected.

I know that this worked early in the 10.10 beta, but it's failing on my fresh 10.10 install. I haven't tried in on anything earlier than 10.10. Any ideas?

Edit: I put some debugging statements in `/etc/gdm/Xsession` to make sure `~/.Xmodmap` was loading, and everything magically started working. I didn't change anything except adding some echos, and it's still working now that I reverted my changes and restarted again. Strangest thing I ever saw.

One thing I realized is that the "remap Caps Lock to Escape" part of the Xmodmap was always working. It was just the Delete/Menu swap that failed. I'll leave this question open for now in case anyone else has the same problem, since I don't actually know why the problem stopped.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem myself, been driving me nuts. If I figure out the cause I'll be sure to post an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's silly but as a workaround you could just autostart `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.

Also you could check `/etc/gdm/Xsession` for the line `usermodmap="$HOME/.Xmodmap"` and if it isn't there just append it at the end of the file. If you're the only user of the system just put your changes into `/etc/X11/Xmodmap`.

Comment: How do you "autostart" commands?

Comment: See [Autostarting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autostarting). The easiest is probably to just add an entry to `Settings->Session and Startup`, or something along those lines.

Comment: Or for example, add it to your shell, so if you open shells often then it will run it. First thing I do when I enter Gnome is open a shell most of the time, so that is one way that works.

Answer (score 8):

Late to the party, but this drove me nuts as well ; and, stubborn as I am, giving up was not an option.

Basically this is what I tried, (as my user, or root if necessary)

- ~/.Xmodmap only
- ~/.xsession, ~/.xsessionrc
- ~/.gnomerc
- ~/.xprofile
- ~/.xinitrc
- /etc/X11/Xsession.d/myscript
- /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ (*config files, didn't touch it*)

(Actually, adding the `xmodmap` command to `~/.bashrc` worked, but it requires to start a terminal each time after login)

A few years ago(?), `xkb` was chosen to deal with keys mapping and configuration (interfacing with X), but `xmodmap` might also request key related changes to X, after `xkb` did its work during the X session initialization.

The problem is when should these xmodmap settings happen?
It *seems* those  above files are processed too early in the process, and either X was not ready to accept xmodmap changes, or xkb would overwrite them.
<sup>Note: I added some "tracking" to these files to ensure they were actually running at some time!</sup>

**A solution that seems to work**

I was not keen to add a `.desktop` file initially (a simple one line script had to be enough), but that works, so here it is.
The solution comes from [How to remap or swap special keyboard keys in Linux?](https://ictsolved.me/blog/linux/remap-key-in-linux) "solution 1"

Basically create `~/.config/autostart/my-xmodmap.desktop` file, and put in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyXmodmap
Exec=/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/me/.Xmodmap
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

replace `me` with your username (note that I didn't bother to try `~/` or `$HOME` that may work equally well in place of `/home/me`, and the full path of xmodmap is likely not necessary...), and add the exec bit

```
chmod +x ~/.config/autostart/my-xmodmap.desktop
```

The xmodmap commands have to be in a `~/.Xmodmap` file in this case (or use the `-e` option, or choose another file name!). Log out and back in.

Note that you might create the starting program from "Startup Applications".

Another solution would be to forget xmodmap and learn how to configure `xkb`!

**Edit** (again)

Sometimes, maybe 25% of the logons, the `xmodmap` still seems not working - while the command is actually run (a tracker proves that). The only conclusion I might come to at this time is that the `xkb` process does run late in the logon process, and may end after the `xmodmap` has run. Looks like a race condition... So, finally, I changed the autostart desktop file `exec` line to

```
Exec=$HOME/bin/mystart &
```

(note the `&`)
`mystart` is a script in a new directory `bin` I created that contains

```
#!/bin/bash    
sleep 5
/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/me/.Xmodmap &
date >> /tmp/xmodmap-has-run
```

and

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/mystart
```

The script sleeps 5 seconds before to run xmodmap, and tracks when it did run (in the file `/tmp/xmodmap-has-run`).

Hopefully that will be all!

Comment: Editing xkb confituration worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1090892/1021380

Answer (score 4):

Here is, perhaps a better answer then: http://cweiske.de/howto/xmodmap/ar01s06.html

You may have to tweak it a little bit to work for you but the instructions are all there.

Comment: This instructions are for KDE, but if I look at the Gnome equivalent (`/etc/gdm/Xsession`), the lines that link says to add are already in it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have a syntax error in your `~/.Xmodmap` file?

Try running:

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

That should fire an error if there are any.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this looks like a (very) long standing issue, and it is just because after Gnome 3.6, `xmodmap` support was dropped.

This is discussed in [Remap keys on GNOME3.8 using xmodmap?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107434/remap-keys-on-gnome3-8-using-xmodmap) and [Bug 873656 - .Xmodmap file not loaded by Gnome 3.x](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=873656) .

The solution is to move to `xkb`. There is a bit of help from [comment 29](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=873656#c29) in the second link.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same weird problem, trying to start up my `xmodmap` while logging in my session (Ubuntu 13.04). I finally made it work with a `.xinitrc` file in my Home folder where I put my command, but with absolute paths to it, that is:

`/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/MYNAME/.Xmodmap`

Then I had to reboot (not just relog) so that it would be executed.

Comment: This does not work under Ubuntu 14.04, for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways:

1. Autostart `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/749662
2. Add it "properly" to the Xsession file (to know what Display Manager you are using you can do this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20376/548454):

   - If you are using "GNOME Display Manager" (gdm) you can check `/etc/gdm/Xsession` for the line

     ```
     usermodmap="$HOME/.Xmodmap"
     ```

     and if it isn't there just append it at the end of the file.
   - If you are using "Simple Desktop Display Manager" (sddm) you can get this same functionality by checking `/etc/sddm/Xsession` for the block:

     ```
     usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
     sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

     if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
          xmodmap "$usermodmap"
     fi

     if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
          xmodmap $sysmodmap
     fi
     ```

     and if it isn't there just append it at the end of the file.
     (from: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/8e7em8/comment/dxtg314/)
3. Directly edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` as explained here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1161870

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).