# What is Launch (c) key in Kubuntu

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys

I fiddle with shortcuts in Kubuntu and stumble on this option. Can someone tell me what is this Launch (C) key?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some keyboards have dedicated multimedia keys to launch applications. `Launch (C)` is [one of 16 symbolic codes](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/howto_keyboard.php) for such launchers: `XF86Launch[0-9A-F]`.