# xmodmap reverting periodically

Tags: keyboard, settings, xmodmap, 13.10

I'm using `xmodmap` to swap control and command keys on my Macbook pro. However, periodically the key revert back to their original state and this is becoming quite annoying.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 and I can remember when this situation started occurring was when the system got a keyboard settings (in the system settings) update. Any ideas as to how to either:

1. delete the keyboard settings, or
2. stop the keyboard settings from reverting my keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How persistently remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen when your PC goes to sleep?  If so, make sure the keyboard is plugged into the PC and not the monitor. [Xmodmap settings are not honored when keyboard devices are hotplugged](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/287215).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that gnome is reverting the caps behavior, I had this problem as well.

You can change the gnome settings with gnome-tweaks (which you can apt install if you don't have it already)

Then run gnome-tweaks, select "Keyboard and Mouse" and then "Advanced Layout Options" - and then you can choose the caps lock behavior there instead of calling xmodmap.

Answer (score 0):

According to several sources such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7190/why-wont-my-xmodmap-file-load-on-login) it is due to the fact that xmodmap is not supported anymore (at least in Ubuntu). In my case, xmodmap is "reverted" when I attach my laptop to a new screen and keyboard after a suspend.

I have not found a solution that works 100%, but I put the `xmomap` command both in the Startup Programs and in `.bashrc` so that when xmodmap is reverted I can quickly fix it by opening a terminal.