# Xmodmap key mappings reverting periodically

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

Possible duplicate of this [xmodmap reverting periodically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336210/xmodmap-reverting-periodically?noredirect=1), but since there is no life in there and the "answer field" is just for answers, I have to create a new question. Six years later on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS I have the same problem as in the above link. Key mappings revert periodically. It doesn't only happen when my computer goes to sleep. I have an ASUS Zen laptop. Has anyone solved the problem yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How persistently remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-persistently-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04).  Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29603/how-do-i-clear-xmodmap-settings.  FYI: We want all information packed into fewer questions so they are not spread out -- If you edit an older question (or answer) it will place the question back to the top of "active" no matter how old it is.  This is better than starting a new question!

Comment: **@Nmath** I disagree: I've just voted to close the old answer as a duplicate of the newer one you found on top of adding a close vote to this one!  **0:-)**  So **SofaGuy** thank for pointing this out!  **;-)**