# How to remap keys in Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME Shell)

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, remapping

Trying to swap <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>.

`xmodmap` doesn't seem to work for anything other than `xev` output. Doesn't work in other cases.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using xkb worked.

Edit this file: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`. Don't forget to use sudo with something like `sudo -i gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`

It'll be fairly straight forward what's going on in there. Key is defined on the left, and effect is defined on the right. Maintain the indentation and all that.

Should work for any kind of remapping.

You'll need to log out and back in (or use the following commands) for changes to take effect:

```
setxkbmap fr # if you are using french azerty layout
setxkbmap us # if you are using US qwerty layout
... And so on
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried remapping ALT key to L_CTRL.

Comment: CTRL_L -> ATL_L does not work for me. After some test I think this could be related to my keyboard: a mac keyboard (It's ubuntu on an old mac book air laptop) because it works with an external one.

Comment: Used this answer to map PgUp to Left and PgDn to Right on my Dell XPS which has *tiny* Left and Right keys with *tiny* PgUp and PgDn keys far too close together!